# Is it possible Facebook PHP SDK 4.0 and Graph API v2.8?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, php-5.2

I am using Facebook PHP SDK 4.0 along with Graph API v2.2. I wondered if it is possible to use Graph API v2.8 with this PHP SDK 4.0 (I've got PHP 5.2 installed on my server and I can not use PHP SDK 5.0).

Currently, I use the following code to obtain the user ID

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => $facebookAppId,
  'secret' => $facebookSecret
));
$user = $facebook->getUser();
if ($user) {
    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
    $user_id = $user_profile['id'];
}
```

I was warned that the API v2.2 will be deprecated late this month, and I am trying to migrate my code to API v2.8.

Thank you very much.

Comment: IIRC the SDK v4 did not provide a way to specify the API version via configuration/at initialization. If you don’t have a problem modifying the source files directly, overwriting the base API address in base_facebook.php is probably the easiest way to specify the API version for all calls.

Comment: Hi. Thank you very much for your answer.

I only need to make Facebook users to login, and get their user IDs. For that task, I suspect that I do not need even the SDK. I've been browsing this simple proposal (http://wp-time.com/login-with-facebook-using-api-in-php/) and I am considering to implement it without the SDK.

Answer (score 0):

// Initialize the Facebook PHPSDK5 and v2.8.

```
$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
  'app_id'                => 'xxxxxxxxxxxx',
  'app_secret'            => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
  'default_graph_version' => 'v2.8',
]);

$helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();
try {
  $accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken();
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
  // There was an error communicating with Graph
  echo $e->getMessage();
  exit;
}

if (isset($accessToken)) {
  // Logged in.
  $_SESSION['facebook_access_token'] = (string) $accessTokenLong;
}

$fb->setDefaultAccessToken($_SESSION['facebook_access_token']);

$me = $fb->get('/me');
$me_array = $me->getGraphEdge()->asArray();
```